# How to define string variable in SQL server, so I can use the string in multiple place in program and make refactor easier?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql

In high level programming language such as Java or Swift, if I want to use a string multiple times in the same program, I can define a string variable to represent that string, so to avoid typing the same string in multiple places. at the same time, making refracting the string easier

In Java

```
final String myStringConstant = "hello world";
```

In Swift

```
let myStringConstant = "hello world"
```

I was just wondering if it possible to do the same in Microsoft SQL Server? I have seen code that type the same string value in multiple places in the code, which makes it very easy to misspell the string in one of the place and therefore screw up the program. A string variable that used to represent the string would be extremely useful.

Comment: `Declare @myStringConstant  varchar(100)`. It will accept Size upto `8000`. If you want to store a string of length more than 8000 then use `Max`

Comment: Declare @myStringConstant varchar(100) = 'hello world'

Comment: If a variable is not what you are looking for because you want this value available in multiple procedures why not put it in a table?

Comment: @Prdp and GuidoG, Thank you both for the suggestion. I was wondering, if I defined a string at the top of a tsql script and this script is divided into several section by the "go" keyword, will I be able to reference the string in each sections between the keyword "go"?

Comment: Why you need `GO` in scripts it is SSMS specific keyword. Not gonna work when call the script from some other client

Comment: If your T-SQL script contains `GO`, it's actually an SQLCMD script. SQLCMD has [variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/scripting/sqlcmd-use-with-scripting-variables), which fulfil the same purpose. Despite the name, however, they're more like macros, since the replacement is purely textual, and the value cannot be set from an SQL command.

Answer (score 4):

It's impossible, but you can create scalar user-defined function that return this constant

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_HelloWorld ()
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) 
AS
BEGIN 
    RETURN 'Hello world'
END
```

Note that unlike `final` in java scalar function in T-SQL can decrease perfomance.

Comment: if possible, Could you please provide an short code example?

Comment: Instead of a scalar function why not put this type of data in a table?

Comment: @SeanLange I think autor ask about hardcoded constants, not settings stored somewhere

Comment: If it is a hard coded constant doesn't that pretty define what you could put in a table? At least if the "constant" changes you don't have to change any code. And scalar functions are horrible for performance.

Comment: Question was about something similar to `final`. Of course, scalar functions is not equals `final` in JAVA, but I cannot find something better. you should use `APPLY` or `SELECT .. FROM` to read from table without scalar function . sometimes write `dbo.fn_HelloWorld()` easily then `SELECT Value FROM dbo.fn_Option('HelloWorld')`. With scalar function code is shorter

Comment: I'm answering question "How to hardcode constant in T-SQL"

Comment: @SeanLange Do you really think above function will have performance impact though am not a big fan of scalar functions,  this looks reasonable. Probably I would change the `Max` to `8000` unless it is really required

Comment: @Prdp - This probably doesn't make a huge impact but it does perpetuate the overuse of scalar functions. And what happens when the OP needs 20 of these values? We end up with 20 such functions instead of a Settings table.

Comment: @SeanLange Even 100 functions like this, just setting a string will not have any impact. There will be constant scan other than I don't think anything will be there.

Comment: Sure the performance isn't a huge deal but what a nightmare to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

My solution to a similar need was to write a custom script processing tool as an alternative to sqlcmd.  This tool allows you to define "substitution variables", which are like macros that can be substituted anywhere in code.  The substitution variable definitions are hidden in SQL comments, using a syntax similar to your examples:

```
-- !x! sub MyStringConstant hello world
```

where `!x!` is a token that identifies this as a command to the script processor, `sub` is the command to define a substitution variable, and the rest should be obvious.  If you're amenable to trying an alternative to sqlcmd, you can get this alternative script processor from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/execsql

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @var int = 12;
select @var;
select * from bid;
select @var;
```

but it will not survive a `go;`